# json array only gets populated with first value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

Hi i have a problem with a local file wich stores some json data

```
{
  "tournament": [{
    "TeamName": "AS Roma",
    "TeamPlayer": "Rickard"
  } {
    "TeamName": "Inter",
    "TeamPlayer": "Bobban"
  }]
}​
```

Then on buttonclick i try to populate an array with this data. But it only takes "AS Roma" and "Rickard" instead of "As Roma" "Rickard" AND "Inter" "Bobban".

```
// Get teams
var url = "http://localhost:57608/json/teams.txt";
$("#btnGetTeams").on('click', function() {
    var allItems = [];
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, team) {
            allItems.push({
                theTeam: team.tournament.TeamName,
                thePlayer: team.tournament.TeamPlayer
            });
        });
        $.each(allItems, function(i, val) {
            $('#teams').append('<p>' + val.theTeam + val.thePlayer + '</p>');
        });
    });
});​
```

So instead of output AS Roma Rickard Inter Bobban, it only writes AS Roma Rickard. 
What am i doing wrong?

**Update Fully working code thanks to Sushanth**

```
// Get teams
var url = "http://localhost:57608/json/teams.txt";
$("#btnGetTeams").on('click', function () {
                var allItems = [];
                $.getJSON(url,
                         function (data) {                               
                                 $.each(data.tournament, function (i) {
                                     allItems.push({
                                         theTeam: data["tournament"][i]["TeamName"],
                                         thePlayer: data["tournament"][i]["TeamPlayer"],
                                     });
                                 });
                             $.each(allItems, function (i, val) {
                                 $('#teams').append('<p>' + val.theTeam + val.thePlayer + '</p>');
                             });                                 
                         });
            });
```

With Json

```
{
"tournament": [
        {
            "TeamName": "AS Roma",
            "TeamPlayer": "Rickard" 
        },
        { 
            "TeamName": "Inter",
            "TeamPlayer": "Bobban" 
        }
            ]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing **comma in your JSON**

```
},  <-- Missing comma between two objects
 {
```

Also you are accessing the json in a wrong way .. Your json is an **array of Objects**

```
$.each(data.tournament, function (i, team) {
       allItems.push({
                        theTeam : team.TeamName,
                        thePlayer: team.TeamPlayer
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/77muQ/)**

[image]

Try this Way with bracket Notation..

```
$.each(data.tournament, function(i) {
    allItems.push({
        theTeam: data["tournament"][i]["TeamName"],
        thePlayer: data["tournament"][i]["TeamPlayer"],
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Bracket Notation](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/77muQ/1/)**

If this does not work use a for loop

```
var allItems = [];
var data = data.tournament;
var i = 0;
for(key in data){
     allItems.push({
        theTeam: data[i].TeamName,
        thePlayer: data[i].TeamPlayer,
    });

}
```

**[For Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/77muQ/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for spotting a missing comma. Though i tried change the code as you said data.tournament. But now i get no output instead :/

Comment: I can see that the fiddle shows a working example. But if i do the same, except i also have to include the .getJson result gives me nothing.

Comment: when using debugger i get, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: thanks for still hanging around :), see update for new code inside click event

Comment: In which line do you see the error ?? Check if you see the error inside the click event

Comment: $.each(data.tournament, function (i, team) { get anonymous function on this

Comment: put a condition if( data != null) then do $.each.. Also try to log the data object and see what it contains

Comment: added if(! data == null) and then it went trough without error. But still no output. I added alert(allItems[0]); after the first $each and it gives me a popup saying "undefined"

Comment: update i did alert(allItems.length); this gives me 0. The array is empty after first $.each has run through

Comment: comment both your $.each and do console.log(data).. Check what you get

Comment: i dont know if i did exactly what u asked for. But i added a console.log(Data) after the first .each and it gave me something like this [
Object
tournament: Object
TeamName: "AS Roma"
TeamPlayer: "Rickard"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
]

Comment: console.log(data.tournament) give me undefined

Comment: I meant to say comment out the two each statements and then do console.log

Comment: Check the edited post .. Your data is supposed to look this way

Comment: yeah, but i still only got 1 Object instead of two :S. Is it something with my json that is wrong?

Comment: Did you set the missing comma

Comment: If that is the json , then this should work .. Don't know where this is getting messed up

Comment: Is it a problem that my file that holds my json is named teams.txt instead of teams.json?

Comment: Nope that should not be a problem ..You need to stringyfy to JSON ..var data= JSON.stringify(data)  .. Also check the bracket notation in the post

Comment: I have added couple of additions in the post .. check that .. Use the for loop without stringyfy

Comment: Perfect i get the two objects using bracket notation. Using console.log(data). But $.each(allItems, function (i, val) {
                                     $('#teams').append('<p>' + val.theTeam + val.thePlayer + '</p>');
                                 }); Does not print out the objects. Do i need to use brackets here aswell?

Comment: Try with bracket notation.. That is not a compulsion though ... Otherwise try it this way $.each(allItems, function(i) {
    $('#teams').append('<p>' + allItems[i]["theTeam"] + allItems[i]["thePlayer"] + '</p>');
});​

Comment: Wow great, now it is fully working. Thanks alot for spending all this time helping me.

Comment: Can i remove the updated post from my original post and instead put in the code that is fully working?

Comment: @rickard .. Glad to have helped ..:)  .. Sure , I don't think that should be a problem

Comment: lol, never gets the code to look good. How do u indent the code to look good? :)